# Initializing Object Property

Tags: javascript, eloquent, this, initializing

I've been following along Eloquent Javascript and have come across this piece of code:

```
var protoRabbit = {
  speak: function(line) {
    console.log("The " + this.type + " rabbit says '" +
                line + "'");
  }
};
```

Coming from a background in C/C++, this syntax threw me off. Where did the property *type* come from? Is it added to protoRabbit when we run protoRabbit.speak()? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks for the replies. I apologize as it seems that I didn't make my question very clear. What I'm confused about is whether or not the property 'type' has to exist before we initialize it. As in:

```
var protoRabbit = {type: "some value", speak: ... };
```

Is it automatically added as a property when we initialize it? If protoRabbit was const, would that violate the const initialization?

Comment: Go some further through the code and you'll notice that the method is not called as `protoRabbit.speak()`, but on an object that will indeed have a `.type` property. And if you just tried to invoke it like that, it would indeed come up as `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm confused about is whether or not the property 'type' has to exist before we initialize it ... Is it automatically added as a property when we initialize it? If protoRabbit was const, would that violate the const initialization?

You can set any key on an object at any time, without initializing it first. Whether or not the variable is `const` doesn't matter, because the object ref isn't being changed, the object itself is being mutated in place. You would only run into trouble if you tried assigning a different object to `protoRabbit`.

```
var protoRabbit = {
  speak: ...
};
```

This creates an object with one property named `speak`.

```
protoRabbit.type = "killer";
```

This creates a property on `protoRabbit` called `type`. It doesn't exist until this line.

Variables in JavaScript, specifically `var`, are different. [Their reference is hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the lexical scope where they are declared, so that earlier references won't break. `let` doesn't get hoisted, and follows different scope semantics.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was confused about.

Answer (score 2):

> Where did the property type come from?

Nowhere in that code. If you call the function you will see that it is `undefined`.

```js
var protoRabbit = {
  speak: function(line) {
    console.log("The " + this.type + " rabbit says '" +
                line + "'");
  }
};

protoRabbit.speak("{line variable}");
```

---

Having dug the book out. This appears to be the section of code you are talking about:

> ```
> var protoRabbit = {
> speak : function ( line ) {
> console.log (" The " + this . type + " rabbit says '" +
> line + " '") ;
> }
> };
> var killerRabbit = Object.create(protoRabbit);
> killerRabbit.type = "killer";
> killerRabbit.speak ("SKREEEE !") ;
> // → The killer rabbit says 'SKREEEE !'
> ```

You can see the `type` property defined on the `killerRabbit` object just a few lines later.